# Bad URI in rake routes rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

config/routes.rb

```
get '/news-views(/:page)',to: redirect("/car-news/%{page}")
```

when I hit

```
/news-views/
```

it gives an Bad Uri but when I hit`/news-views/1` it works
i want it to work without page also

[image]

Comment: I update question and add error pic also

Comment: Remove `()` like `get '/news-views/:page', to: redirect("/car-news/%{page}")` and add `get '/news-views', to: redirect("/car-news")` if you really need the root path `/news-views` of redirecting

Comment: get '/news-views/:title(/:page)' => redirect('/car-news/:title/%{page}')

no basically i have another url also due to which it impacts and it works fine

Comment: Yes, it's work when you pass an `:page` like /news-views/my-example, but when you go on root like `/news-views` it didn't because rails redirect to literally `/car-news/%{page}` and `{}` aren't url encoded, that's why the bad uri